# type_trait 's have member Failure if use global function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I found detect class 's member use global template function is not work:

```
void printinfo(std::true_type)
{
    cout<<"true_type!";
}
void printinfo(std::false_type)
{
    cout<<"false_type!";
}
class TestAA
{
 public:
        void foo();
};
class TestBB;
template<typename T,typename =decltype(&T::foo)>
std::true_type havefoo(T*){return{};}
std::false_type havefoo(...){return{};}
int main()
{
    printinfo(havefoo((TestAA*)nullptr));
     printinfo(havefoo((TestBB*)nullptr));
}
class TestBB
{
 public:
         void foo();
};
```

it  fail detect TestBB's foo,is normal? or a complier bug? gcc 4.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler hasn't seen the definition of `TestBB` at the point of the call to `printinfo`, only the forward declaration. At that point it doesn't know about any members of `TestBB`.